# How do I update multiple data in database column?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

This is my group controller page. So basically I want to create groups form the existing users in the group. I have two tables in my db, one is 'users', another one is 'groups'. So while creation of any group it checks whether a users in db or not. If the users are in the db it should create group and update a column in users table named 'group_id' to '1', so one user cannot be in multiple groups. The problem is, the below code only works for one user, it only updates group_id for the first user or input, not for the rest. I want to update 'group_id' for all the users that am using to create group. I know below code only works for one users. I want to know how to do this for multiple users using a loop or something. How do I update 'group_id' for the all input or users? here is the code am using,

```
public function store(Request $request) {

  $member_name = $request->member_name;
  $users = User::where('name', '=', $member_name)->first();

  $affected = DB::table('users')->where('name', '=', $member_name) ->update(['group_id' => 1]);

  foreach ($request->all() as $key => $affected) {
    dump($key, $affected);
  }

  if ($users) {
    $group = new Group([
      'name' => $request->get('name'),
      'idea' => $request->get('idea'),
      'member_name' => $request->get('member_name'),
      'group_id' => $request->get('group_id'),
    ]);
    if ($group->save()) {
      return redirect()->to('users');
    } else {
      echo 'users are not in the db';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question still not clear to me

Comment: Your question is not clear at all but to answer part of the question, in your query, the `->where('name', '=', $member_name)` will target a single user so it is normal that only one user is concerned by your update

Comment: Could you show us [a little more of the surrounding code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?